# Add rewrite rule for rewrite endpoint

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, endpoints

I've created an rewrite endpoint with the [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/) function … here is the whole contruct:

```
// Register to query vars

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars');


function add_query_vars( $vars ) {

    $vars[] = 'account';

    return $vars;

}


// Add rewrite endpoint


add_action( 'init', 'account_page_endpoint' );

function account_page_endpoint() {

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'account', EP_ROOT );

}



// Account template

add_action( 'template_include', 'account_page_template' );

function account_page_template( $template ) {

    if( get_query_var( 'account', false ) !== false ) {

        return locate_template( array( 'account.php' ) );

    }

    return $template;

}
```

This works great so far when i enter a url like example.com/account/username ... but the links in the site are still like example.com?account=username.

How do i redirect from the parameter version to rewritten version? Is it necessary to add a additional rewrite rule or is there any function that these links have to run through?

The account links on the site itself are created by this function:

```
function account_url( $user_id ) {

    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    return add_query_arg( 'account', strtolower( $user->user_login ), get_home_url() );

}
```

Comment: What code is generating those links?

Comment: @Milo: Ive edited the question and added the function that are used to create these account links/urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite rules only handle incoming requests, they aren't involved in link generation.

The primary WordPress rewrite system is parsed internally with PHP, you won't see any changes to an `.htaccess` file when you add an endpoint. The basic .htaccess rules essentially say "If this isn't a request for a physical file or directory on the server, then hand the request over to WordPress".

Your `account_url` function has to handle both "ugly" and "pretty" cases when it outputs the account URLs. We can look at the built in [`get_permalink` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) to see how WordPress handles this, here's an abbreviated version:

```
$permalink = get_option('permalink_structure');
if ( '' != $permalink ) {
    // output a pretty permalink
} else {
    // output an ugly permalink
}
```

The `permalink_structure` option holds the chosen pattern if pretty permalinks are enabled, we know pretty permalinks are disabled if it's empty.

Comment: On point! Thank you, that was exactly what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT 2

To use pretty permalinks, such as example.com/account/john
you need to activate in your admin area, in the permalink settings,
and activate it on you server.
You told us in comments that you used nginx, I know better apache so here is a tutorial which could help you.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-nginx-for-wordpress-permalinks/

**EDIT**

I went too fast, forget about my suggestion of add_rewrite_rule,
I think that with using add_rewrite_endpoint you have to use the "template_redirect" hook instead of the "template_include" one.

**END EDIT**

According to the code you show, I would add this to your account_page_endpoint function

```
add_rewrite_rule('^account/([a-z0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?account=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

It does not modify the .htaccess file, however you can refresh the rules.

You may need to refresh the rules after this modification.

Two possibilities:

-either you add, right after the line of code above, the call to the flush rewrite function like this:

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

-or you can go in you admin area, in the permalink settings and re save your current settings.

Comment: Ive added your function to init hook and flushed the rewrite rules by saving the permalinks ... but altough it seems like exactly what i need this has no effect ...

Comment: With this function there should be some changes visible in the rewrite rules of the .htaccess file? Right now it doesn't seem like anything of that rules have changed …

Comment: It does not deal with the server, I updated my answer.

Comment: Doesn't change anything even with a flush_rewrite_rules directly after the function ... this rewrite rule redirect ./?account=foobar to ./account/foobar?

Comment: Well it seems like your function does exactly the same like add_rewrite_endpoint( 'account', EP_ROOT ); ... so without that function and only your solution ./account/foobar/ still works. But the problem is that the links in the site are still like ./?account=foobar so it is necessary to change either the links to the rewritten format or redirect ./?account=foobar to ./account/foobar/

Comment: Yeah i could change them easily (Ive added the function that creates this links in the question) … but it seems not very elegant to "hardcode" this. When mod rewrite is not active or vice versa it will fail

Comment: Something like this: <a href="<?php echo account_url( get_current_user_id() ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Account', 'Theme' ); ?></a> ... The user id is passed differently in the comments and other places of course